# Energy of a function and its Fourier transform

Tags: complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-transform

"Calculate the Fourier transform of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+4}$ and verify that 
$\int_{R} |f(x)|^2 dx  = \int_R |\hat{f}(p)|^2dp$.

If I did it right,  $ \hat{f}(p) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\pi}{2} 
  \begin{cases}
    e^{-2p}       & \quad \text{if } p > 0\\
    e^{2p}  & \quad \text{if } p < 0
  \end{cases}
$ 

Please let me know if I made mistakes.

For the second part, I don't know how to proceed. I would start stating that both $f(x)$ and $\hat{f}(p)$ $\in L^2(R) $. Now I know from lessons, but don't know how to prove it, that the energy of those functions is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+4)^2}\,dx&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2\sec^2(x)}{16\sec^4(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac14 \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac\pi{16}
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac\pi8 e^{-4|p|}\,dp&=\int_0^\infty \frac\pi4 e^{-4p}\,dp\\\\
&=\frac\pi 4\left.\left(\frac{e^{-4p}}{-4}\right)\right|_{p=0}^{p\to \infty}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{16}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Could you please explicit how you got the second integral?

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac\pi8 e^{-4|p|}\,dp=\frac\pi4 \int_0^\infty e^{-4p}\,dp=\frac\pi 4 \left.\left( \frac{e^{-4p}}{-4}\right)\right|_{p=0}^{p\to \infty}=\frac\pi{16}$$

Comment: My bad, I meant the second passage of the first integral, but I got it using the residue theorem. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: For the first integral, I used the substitution $x\to a\tan(x)$.  Then, note that $\cos^2(x)=\frac12+\frac12\cos(2x)$.